# Perl Variable/Regex Issue, how to use store regex matches in a loop preferably without using hashes

Tags: arrays, regex, perl, file, hash

I apologize in advance if this is confusing however this is my issue:

I am trying to write a Perl script that will read data from a long config file, and allow the use to edit and overwrite a certain reocurring line in that file. However, each line that is edited needs to include a number that is unique to that block of text. Let me show an example in order to clarify, the text looks something like this:

```
blah blah durrr
foo hello 23425253 whatever
something something who cares

blah blah durrr
foo hello 78932124 whatever
something something who cares
```

Basically, I need to search the file for lines starting with `foo` containing a number between 1 and 9 digits, and replace that line with a user entered string that contains said digits, such that when the script is run with a user defined entry of `user entry user entry $number user entry`, the resulting text file will look like this:

```
blah blah durrr
user entry user entry 23425253 user entry
something something who cares

blah blah durrr
user entry user entry 78932124 user entry
something something who cares
```

Basically the user needs to be able to replace a line that matches the above criteria, but still be able to enter a token such that the number from the old line will exist in a certain in the new line. Here is the relevant code in my file open/read loop that I have up to this point:

```
if($line =~ /^foo/)
{       
    $line =~ m/(\d\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?\d?)/;
    my $number = $1; 
    $entry =~ s/\$number/$number/;
    $line = $entry\n;
}
```

Basically I am trying to match the number in the line with a regex and store it using the temporary variable $1 (which worksso far), replace instances of `"$number"` in the user entry with the actual variable `$number` (which works so far), and then overwrite that line with the user's entry. (which works so far) My problem is that only the first number matched is ever stored, so instead of each text block having the appropriate number, the first number matched is placed throughout the entire text file, like so:

```
blah blah durrr
user entry user entry 23425253 user entry
something something who cares

blah blah durrr
user entry user entry 23425253 user entry
something something who cares
```

I realize that this issue is because I am assigning my number value to $1, which only stores the first value matched. My first thought was to just assign $number to a match variable one higher each time the loop is run, i.e. $1, $2... $n, however this would require me to change the variable name, which doesnt appear to be possible to do in Perl. I have tried googling the answer which led me to solutions which used hashes and arrays. I am still very new to Perl, I literally jsut started learning it last week this is the first actual script I have written using it, I logically understand what is going on here, however I dont have the perl skills to put it into practice.

If anyone here knows how I can address this issue it would be greatly appreciated!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hashes nor arrays involved, just regular expressions:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my $entry = 'user entry user entry $number user entry';

while (<DATA>) {
    if (s/^foo.*?([0-9]{1,9}).*/$entry/) {
        my $number = $1;
        s/\$number/$number/;
    }
    print;
}

__DATA__
blah blah durrr
foo hello 23425253 whatever
something something who cares

blah blah durrr
foo hello 78932124 whatever
something something who cares
```

Comment: When I use this code, I receive the error "Use of uninitialized value $_ in substitution <s///> at perl.pl line x"

Comment: @XeroG: Have you modified the code, or have you run it copypasted from here?

Comment: Okay, I fixed the error, and the code prints the correct results, however I need to now print those results to a new file. How your code into a write filehandle? My var for the write filehandle is $write.

Comment: @XeroG: You can redirect the output: `perl.pl > output.txt`, or use `print {$write} $_;` instead of the sole `print`.

Answer (score 1):

```
use warnings;
use strict; 

open my $file1, '<', 'in.txt' or die $!;
open my $out, '>', 'out.txt' or die $!;

print "Enter user entry ";
chomp(my $entry = <STDIN>);

print "Enter number: ";
chomp(my $number = <STDIN>);


my $num;
while(<$file1>){
    chomp;
    if (/^foo/){
        ($num) = /(\d+)/;
        print $out "$entry $number $entry" if $num == $number;
    }
    print "$_\n";
}
```